# Converting Experience Cloud Template to Salesforce Template

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I need to have a copy of the Experience cloud template which is a Salesforce template for additional functionality available. Is there a way to convert an already existing Experience Cloud template instead of recreating said template from scratch?

Comment: So you are an Adobe customer and also a DocuSign customer?

Comment: @InbarGazit No, this has nothing to do with Adobe. I am talking about DocuSign launcher for Salesforce.

Comment: Experience Cloud. You mentioned that. This is an Adobe product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no such functionality. You would have to recreate a template from scratch as I was instructed by DocuSign support.